# How to add the mean of the dependent variable when using outreg2?

Tags: stata

I have a set of regressions that are exported using the *community-contributed* Stata command `estout` in the following format:

```
foreach yvar of varlist yvar1 yvar2 {
    eststo: quietly regress `yvar' xvar1 xvar2, robust
    estadd ysumm
}

esttab using mydoc.csv, se stats(N ymean r2_a) replace
```

However, I found that the *community-contributed* command `outreg2` can create better regression tables, so I would like to use that instead.

I would like to include the mean of dependent variable (`ymean`) when using `outreg2` but I cannot call `e(ymean)` as the relevant scalars are not created.

Below is my code:

```
local first_loop yes

foreach yvar of varlist yvar1 yvar2 {
    quietly regress `yvar' xvar1 xvar2, robust
    if "`first_loop'"=="yes"{
        outreg2 using outreg2_test.xls, replace ctitle(`yvar') ///
         addstat(Mean, e(ymean)) label
        local first_loop no
    }
    else {
        outreg2 using outreg2_test.xls, append ctitle(`yvar') ///
         addstat(Mean, e(ymean)) label
    }
}
```

My code above does not work because `outreg2` does not recognize `e(ymean)`.

My questions:

- Is this scalar specific to `estadd`?
- Is there a way I can include mean of dependent variable in the regression output table when using `outreg2`?

Answer (score 2):

It appears that `e(ymean)` is not standard regression output for `regress`.

The simplest method is probably to specify that you wish to report the dependent variable as well (`depvar` option), and that you wish to report the mean as well as the coefficient and standard errors.

For example:

```
outreg2 using outreg2_test.xls, replace ctitle(`yvar') depvar stats(coef se mean) label
```

Note that this method will also report the means of your independent variables.

Alternatively, to report *only* the `ymean` at the bottom of the column, you can summarize your dependent variable and add the mean manually:

```
local first_loop yes

foreach yvar of varlist yvar1 yvar2 {
  quietly regress `yvar' xvar1 xvar2, robust
  quietly summ `yvar'   
  if "`first_loop'"=="yes"{
    outreg2 using outreg2_test.xls, replace ctitle(`yvar') addstat(Mean, r(mean)) label
    local first_loop no
  }
  else {
    outreg2 using outreg2_test.xls, append ctitle(`yvar') addstat(Mean, r(mean)) label
  }
}
```

You can also add the `ymean` to a local macro and use it in your `addstat()` option if preferred, and -depending on your regression analysis- you may want to add `if e(sample)` to your `summarize` command.

Comment: @brendan Thanks for your solutions. The first solution gives what I want, but it creates so many rows (with each mean in one row). However, the second solution creates mean of all observations of a dependent variable, not only the ones used in the regression. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: As noted, try adding `if e(sample)` to your `summ` command (make sure to `summ` after you `regress`).

Comment: @brendan Forgive me if my question is too basic. How to add `if (esample)` to the `summ` command?

Answer (score 1):

The command `estadd ysumm` can also be used before calling `outreg2`:

```
local first_loop yes

foreach yvar of varlist yvar1 yvar2 { 
    quietly regress `yvar' xvar1 xvar2, robust
    estadd ysumm
    if "`first_loop'"=="yes"{
        outreg2 using outreg2_test.xls, replace ctitle(`yvar') ///
           addstat(Mean of dependent variable, e(ymean)) label

        local first_loop no
    }
    else {
        outreg2 using outreg2_test.xls, append ctitle(`yvar') ///
           addstat(Mean of dependent variable, e(ymean)) label
    }
}
```